# Remove quotation marks when exporting

Tags: jasper-reports, quotation-marks

How do you remove quotation marks then exporting `String` values of multiple words?

For example:

```
"Compact Lamber"  
Amazonka  
Eri  
"AM 10-6-7"
```

Should be:

```
Compact Lamber  
Amazonka  
Eri  
AM 10-6-7
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you exporting the String value? In other words, post some JRXML code that shows a minimal example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$F{fieldName} = $F{fieldName}.replace("\"", "")
```